# Multi conditional formatting not working in google sheets. only 3 steps working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

What I am trying to do here,

1. If a cell value AA=>7 the whole row will be "Orange": This is working
2. If a cell value AA=>10 the whole row will be "Red": This is working
3. If another cell V="Cancelled" it will override conditional formatting 1 and 2 the whole row will be white, Red text, and strikethrough: This is working
4. if same "V" cell V="Shipped"  the whole row should be Green and conditional formating 1 2 and 3 will be overridden: This is not working

[image: This is what I did in the Google Sheets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a condition on your 1 and 2 conditions to prevent them from overwriting the failing condition and not interfere with each other

`=AND($AA2>=7, $AA2<=9, $V2<>"Shipped")`

`=AND($AA2>=10, $V2<>"Shipped")`

This means that they only format the cells IF $V2 is not "Shipped" and condition 1 will only work on AA values 7-9

The problem with your conditions is that it can support 2 cases at once. For these issues, we need to completely separate them so that they will not have issues.

Every case should only be under 1 conditional formatting for it to work properly.

[image: sample data]

Also, note the hierarchy of the conditions as it will affect the outcome.

**Reference:**

- [Conditional Formatting](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/highlight-cells-based-multiple-conditions-google-sheets/)